# A Riddle Never Found in the Sky

Tags: riddle

> I stand for two words, both start with C,
>
> In shorthand, sometimes you'll find me,
>
> When you see me it's sometimes bad,
>
> But often I'm an alright lad.
>
> I could be called a wizard,
>
> For I make things disappear,
>
> When you talk of one you used to know,
>
> I am often here.
>
> When you turn me on my side,
>
> I am above equals.
>
> So, what am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> X

I stand for two words, both start with C

> Cross or Chi (Greek letter)

In shorthand, sometimes you'll find me, 
When you see me it's sometimes bad

> X is a shorthand for marking something as incorrect

But often I'm an alright lad.
I could be called a wizard,
For I make things disappear

> X to close a computer window [thanks to noedne for this]

When you talk of one you used to know,
I am often here.

> Referring to a previous lover as one's ex

When you turn me on my side,
I am above equals.

> Rotating x, it becomes +, hence above equals?

Comment: +1, but how does this relate to the title?

Comment: I guess it could mean: never found "i-n- t-h-e s-k-y," but then that would mean that it's a riddle never found in underground rotating hibernating squid formations, too.

Comment: I think the second word it stands for is [ROT13](https://www.rot13.com/)(Puevfg). Also, an alternative way it makes things disappear is [ROT13](https://www.rot13.com/)(ol pybfvat pbzchgre jvaqbjf).

Comment: @Chowzen Correct. Never found in "t-h-e-s-k-y"

Comment: @noedne Both correct

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a:

> Carbon Copy

**My Reasoning**

I stand for two words, both start with C

In Shorthand, sometimes you'll find me

> CC is common email shorthand for two words that start with C: Carbon Copy

I could be called a wizard,

For I make things disappear,

When you talk of one you used to know,

I am often here.

> BCC, or blind carbon copy allows someone to conceal the recipient of the email, thus making who the message is being sent to, disappear or not be seen by other recipients

Comment: An answer to a riddle should explain how it corresponds to every part of the riddle.

Comment: An interesting idea